# NAV2 Getting Started Example error

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

https://navigation.ros.org/getting_started/index.html

I'm following the NAV2 tutorial and this is what happens:

I have everything installed:

```
sudo apt install ros-humble-navigation2
sudo apt install ros-humble-nav2-bringup
sudo apt install ros-humble-turtlebot3*
sudo apt-get install ros-humble-turtlebot3-gazebo
```

Then I set the key environment variables:

```
source /opt/ros/humble/setup.bash
export TURTLEBOT3_MODEL=waffle
export GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH=$GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH:/opt/ros/humble/share/turtlebot3_gazebo/models
```

Then after running:

```
ros2 launch nav2_bringup tb3_simulation_launch.py headless:=False
```

I rush to rviz, set the 2D pose estimation as quick as I can and end up with this in the terminal:

```
[component_container_isolated-6] [INFO] [1669122316.072762902] [amcl]: Creating bond (amcl) to lifecycle manager.
[rviz2-5] [INFO] [1669122320.120000768] [rviz2]: Setting estimate pose: Frame:map, Position(-2.97266, -0.58257, 0), Orientation(0, 0, 0.0273898, 0.999625) = Angle: 0.0547864
[spawn_entity.py-3] [ERROR] [1669122345.950231796] [spawn_entity]: Service %s/spawn_entity unavailable. Was Gazebo started with GazeboRosFactory?
[spawn_entity.py-3] [ERROR] [1669122345.950698437] [spawn_entity]: Spawn service failed. Exiting.
[ERROR] [spawn_entity.py-3]: process has died [pid 20529, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/gazebo_ros/spawn_entity.py -entity turtlebot3_waffle -file /opt/ros/humble/share/nav2_bringup/worlds/waffle.model -robot_namespace -x -2.00 -y -0.50 -z 0.01 -R 0.00 -P 0.00 -Y 0.00 --ros-args'].
```

Some system info
ROS_VERSION=2
ROS_PYTHON_VERSION=3
ROS_LOCALHOST_ONLY=0
ROS_DISTRO=humble
Ubuntu 22 duel booted

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/409723/nav2-getting-started-example-error/) by [Is_that_so](https://answers.ros.org/users/124711/is_that_so/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2022-11-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is no need to rush to rviz to set the pose. You can do this whenever you want.

It seems like gazebo is not starting properly. Start it alone with `gazebo --verbose` and make sure it starts properly. Also with the gazebo path defined. It will download a lot of stuff in the beginning. If this is all good, try the launch file again.

But with the headless:=false it should also show gazebo with the turtlebot and environment. Only then you must set the initial pose.

---

Originally posted by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) with karma: 862 on 2022-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Is_that_so](https://answers.ros.org/users/124711/is_that_so/) on 2022-11-24**:
I started gazebo using `gazebo --verbose` then I closed it. I then sourced my enviroment and ran `ros2 launch nav2_bringup tb3_simulation_launch.py headless:=False` and it finally worked.

**Comment by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) on 2022-11-24**:
Glad to hear that. Could you please click the tick next to my answer, then.